# Batch render same model with different image textures?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, image

Im making a school project and I trying to a the same model, but with different image textures. I need to replace the image with other and cant figure how to batch render this.

Thanks in advance to anyone!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/218730/automatically-generate-100-animations-each-with-a-different-texture-input https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/287923/batch-importing-texturing-and-rendering-via-python